# MySQL query for total sales per month and payment type

Tags: mysql, database, report

Hello i have problem in Mysql query to display monthly report per payment type.
I have database table like this.

**uid | invoice_num | pay_type | trans_date | total**

in pay_type i use enum type, where **0=cash, 1=debit and 2=credit**.

I want to display the data like this.

**Trans_date | Cash | Debit | Credit | Total**
2013-10-01    1000      0          500     1500
etc.

This is my current query but, it return error.

```
SELECT 
(SELECT tgl_transaksi FROM tb_detail_transjual GROUP BY tgl_transaksi) as tanggal,

(SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_detail_transjual
WHERE jenis_trans=0) as cash,

(SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_detail_transjual
WHERE jenis_trans=1) as debit,

(SELECT SUM(total) FROM tb_detail_transjual
WHERE jenis_trans=2) as credit
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CASE WHEN statement.  I haven't tested this but it should work.  You can add a ORDER BY trans_date to the end if you want to sort it.

```
SELECT trans_date, 
    CASE WHEN pay_type = 0 THEN sum(total) ELSE 0 END AS Cash, 
    CASE WHEN pay_type = 1 THEN sum(total) ELSE 0 END AS Debit, 
    CASE WHEN pay_type = 2 THEN sum(total) ELSE 0 END AS Credit, 
    sum(total) AS Total
FROM tb_detail_transjual
GROUP BY trans_date
```

Comment: Hello, query above won't work when i have 2 payment type in one day.

Comment: It should unless you have something else going on in the query.  You will have to be more specific for me to have any idea of what is going on.  Please share the query your using, the error or issue you are getting, and any other relevant code.  Seeing how you have created the table itself might help too.